# What's our policy towards multiple answers from the same user on the same question?

Tags: discussion, answers, etiquette

Prompted by these multiple answers ( [1](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15160/1467) & [2](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15162/1467) ) on the same question.

We had a [brief conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12036/conversation/multiple-answers) and we agreed that having a site-wide consensus would be appropriate.

Is it appropriate for a user to post multiple answers to a question? When yes? When no?

Comment: Just to clarify: they were rather distinct (IMHO) and dealing with two approaches. Any comments would therefore have been dealing with only half the question...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice

Comment: @casey if you read the chat discussion you'll see that I have already expressed my view on that discussion and said why I think it does not apply here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've drafted up an example.

***Question: Is traveling on first class safer?***

✔ **Scenario 1:**

- Answer 1: Yes, because...
- Answer 2: Somewhat, because...

❌ **Scenario 2:**

- Answer 1: Yes, because *reason 1*
- Answer 2: Yes, because *reason 2*

If you have different opinions of a single subject, you can write them in two answers. But if you have multiple reasons supporting the same opinion/concept, there should be a single answer.

For the situation which triggered this question, [MikeFoxtrot's conclusion](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/15160/65) is the same but discussed in two different aspects. I agree with [Federico](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/21876534#21876534) that it should be (and now is) in a single answer.